# Power BI DAX Filter(): load only single column without affecting any filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dax measure, which is calculating the sum of values from the accountcommon table which meets the condition:

```
Term Growth/Increase = CALCULATE([Variance (Organic Loan)],FILTER(AccountCommon,[Variance (Organic Loan)]>0))
```

Currently, Power Bi is loading the whole `AccountCommon` Table in the filter expression, whereas I just want to filter the data based on only a single column  `AccountCommon[AccountNumber]`

Can anyone please help me understand if it's possible to load only a single column in the filter expression without affecting any filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Term Growth/Increase =
CALCULATE (
    [Variance (Organic Loan)],
    FILTER ( ALL ( AccountCommon[AccountNumber] ), [Variance (Organic Loan)] > 0 )
)
```

or

```
Term Growth/Increase =
CALCULATE (
    [Variance (Organic Loan)],
    FILTER ( VALUES ( AccountCommon[AccountNumber] ), [Variance (Organic Loan)] > 0 )
)
```

depending on whether you want to preserve existing filter context on that column or not.

Comment: Hi Alexis, Thanks for the answer, I need to keep all the filters, so I have used values() function and the solution is working. The values() function can either accept only a single column or an entire table. Out of curiosity, if I want to include multiple columns, how can I modify the values() function?

Comment: You can have multiple FILTER arguments inside CALCULATE. One for each column you want to filter.

Comment: Will the columns only work like AND condition i.e. rows will be returned if the conditions on all the column matches, or can they work like OR condition also i.e. rows will be returned if conditions on any of the column matches?

Comment: Filters combine with AND logic.

Comment: Is it possible to use multiple columns with VALUES() function, and they work like OR logic?

Comment: Possible but not quite as easy. Would need a separate post with more specifics to answer well.